# Setting default values to a type created from an object

Tags: typescript

I receive an object from the network and store it in an array. However, not all properties are set in the input. To my surprise that works, although the properties are not optional.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const tasks: Person[] = [];
tasks.push(JSON.parse('{"name": "Johannes"}'));
console.log(tasks);
```

I would like to have the missing properties to have default values. I could use code like:

```
const person: Person = tasks[0];
if (!("age" in person)) person!.age = 65;
```

But that is ugly in that it hard codes property names. Is there an elegant
solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a shallow extend by using the spread operator with a template object containing the default values to use if the deserialized object is missing them:

```
const template: Partial<Person> = { age: 65 };
const person = { ...template, ...tasks[0] };
```

What the code above will do is create an object with all of the values from *template*, and then all of the values of *tasks[0]*.  If a property is set in *tasks[0]* then it will have priority due to being the second object in the spread.